# How is Anisotropic Diffusion dependent on time?

Tags: image-processing

I am currently studying about Anisotropic Diffusion in my Image processing course. The formal definition given in Wikipedia has a partial derivative of the Image with respect to time and the diffusion coefficient C is a function of time as well.

Can anyone explain to me how the time parameter comes into play?

Wikipedia link: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_diffusion

Answer (score 1):

This is not actual time, but a notional time during which diffusion operates on the image. In practice, it corresponds to the number of  iterations of the algorithm.

This is inspired by the real-life diffusion processes which do evolve with time.

Note that in the most common case, C is held constant.